# Bradford Dissolvable Agent not completing scan, application unexpectedly stops without error or report

Tags: windows-7, networking, authentication

I've been trying to connect to a network that uses the dissolvable agent to scan and OK your computer. The scan gets to around 70% ish, I think the last notification is that it's searching for AVG then closes, without report or notification.

I've tried running it in compatibility modes, checking registry, running CCleaner, running as administrator, creating another user account and disconnecting all other HDD's appart from my system drive.
I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, and before I joined the network bradford ran fine and gave me the all okay.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but I have found a solution-it is because the program detects avg still on your computer not completely removed. It must be completely removed in order for it to complete.

Comment: For this to be a complete solution it would be good if you could describe what is needed to completely remove it.